# How can my C program communicate with the CMD?

Tags: c, windows, cmd

I'm trying to create a console program in C that will accept user commands, pass them to the cmd, receive the output from the cmd and then present it to the user through it's own console. Something like a cmd proxy.

As far as I'm aware, they way to facilitate intraprocess communication is through pipes, but I have only managed to do this with applications where both the pipe server and the pipe client are written by me. I'm pretty lost as how I can do that with the cmd.

Comment: While not the best solution, how about using [`_popen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx)?

Comment: Step 1: read lines of text from `stdin` using `fgets()`, pass them to `system()`.  Step 2: pass them to `popen()` instead, read and print response lines until `EOF`, call `pclose()`.  Step 3: Create two pipes (one for writing, one for reading), call `fork()`, close read and write ends of write and read pipes in parent, close write and read ends of write and read pipes in child, use `dup2()` to "rename" write and read pipes to `0` and `1` in child, call `exec("sh")` in child, write commands to and read responses from child in parent. (P.S. Step 3 is considerably trickier. :-) )

Comment: @SteveSummit, it seems you skipped step 3a: switch to a Unix system or at least the Linux subsystem in Windows 10. There's no `fork` in the Windows API. The kernel supports it for other subsystems such as WSL.

Comment: It's certainly possible to run cmd.exe using piped standard I/O. It can even be a detached process (i.e. not attached to an instance of conhost.exe), which is useful if you're displaying the shell in a custom GUI instead of using the built-in console (conhost.exe). Just start working on the problem, and ask a question when you hit a wall.